# How to set up zsh autocompletion correctly?

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I'm having some trouble setting up the `zsh` shell correctly. My `.zshrc` looks like this

```bash
# Enable Powerlevel10k instant prompt. Should stay close to the top of ~/.zshrc.
if [[ -r "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh" ]]; then
  source "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh"
fi

source "$HOME/prg/external/zsh-autocomplete/zsh-autocomplete.plugin.zsh"

export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"
export ZSH_CONFIG_DIR="$HOME/.config/zsh"

ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"

plugins=(
    git
    zsh-vi-mode 
    zsh-history-substring-search 
    zsh-syntax-highlighting
)

source "$ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh"

source "$ZSH_CONFIG_DIR/aliases_and_exports.sh"
source "$ZSH_CONFIG_DIR/setup_pyenv.sh"
source "$ZSH_CONFIG_DIR/setup_yabai.sh"
source "$ZSH_CONFIG_DIR/setup_autocompletion.sh"

# To customize prompt, run `p10k configure` or edit ~/.p10k.zsh.
[[ ! -f ~/.p10k.zsh ]] || source ~/.p10k.zsh
```

As you can see I use four zsh-plugins `zsh-vi-mode, zsh-history-substring-search, zsh-autocomplete`, and `zsh-syntax-highlighting`. According to the GitHub of [`zsh-autocomplete`](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete#configuration) I should be able to change the behaviour of how the autocomplete works, by adding some commands to the `.zshrc` (see `$ZSH_CONFIG_DIR/setup_autocomplete.sh`), i.e.

```bash
zstyle ':compinit' arguments -D -i -u -C -w
autoload -U compinit && compinit
bindkey '^I' menu-select "$terminfo[kcbt]" menu-select
bindkey -M menuselect '^I' menu-complete "$terminfo[kcbt]" reverse-menu-complete
```

and according to the developer this should `Make Tab go straight to the menu and cycle there`, but when I try to do this, Tab does not cycle through the menu but Shift+Tab works.

On top of that, writing something (e.g. `echo $HOME_`) in the shell and then pressing the `Up` key to go through the history of the commands, which start with what has been written already (e.g. `echo $HOME_A`, then `echo $HOME_B`, etc), does not work anymore.

Do I need to to anything special before or after the `bindkey` command works on macOS? Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Turns out the issue is the `zsh-vi-mode` plugin. Once you turn that off, everything works as expected... Now the question is, what kind of remapping one needs to do to get all three plugins to work nicely with each other.

Comment: according to developers it says this command
bindkey '\t' menu-select "$terminfo[kcbt]" menu-select
bindkey -M menuselect '\t' menu-complete "$terminfo[kcbt]" reverse-menu-complete

But you are using ^I instead of \t.
I am just curious.